# is it possible to push a viewcontroller from within a subclass?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, subclass

I've created a navigationController application and it has within the stack a subclass which basically looks like this:

- rootViewController
- leaderboardViewController <----- UITableView within this VC set to files owner

  - UITableViewCell

    - UICollectionView <----- this is where I'm trying to push a new view controller

Inside the collectionView didSelect method which is in the 
UITableViewCell.m file:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    userCell *user = (userCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    imageTag = ((UICollectionView *)user).tag;
    leaderboardViewController *leaderboardView = [[leaderboardViewController alloc] init];
    [imageManager getInsightWithCompletionBlock:^(UIImage *image){
          [leaderboardView postInfo];

    }];
}
```

then in the leaderBoardViewController.m is the postInfo method:

```
-(void)postInfo
{
    NSLog(@"posted!");
    largeInsight *detailedInsight = [[largeInsight alloc] initWithNibName:@"largeInsight" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailedInsight animated:YES];        
}
```

the NSLog appears in the debug area so the postInfo function is running but it just doesn't push the new viewController. I'm guessing it's something I've missed or I'm doing something I'm not supposed to... I don't think its because of the UICollectionView subclass as I'm referring back to the leaderboardViewController. I just don't know why it's not running that navigationController bit of code. Has anyone come across this same problem? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

with some help, I've removed the new instance variable of `leaderboardViewController` and put in `NSNotificationCenter` that points to the VC to run the `postInfo` method when the notification is sent:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    userCell *user = (userCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    imageTag = ((UICollectionView *)user).tag;

    [imageManager getInsightWithCompletionBlock:^(UIImage *image){[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PostCellInformation" object:self];
    }];
}
```

then in leadboardVC.m where the collectionView is initialised:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(postInfo) name:@"PostCellInformation" object:nil];
```

Comment: I don't see where you added the leaderboardView to the navigationcontroller. You are running postInfo from the leaderboardView class. Check to see if leaverboardView.navigationController == nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line...

```
leaderboardViewController *leaderboardView = [[leaderboardViewController alloc] init];
```

...creates a **new** instance of `leaderboardViewController`.  Since it's new, it's not part of the current view controller hierarchy that's controlling the display.  That means that anything it pushes is also not part of the current display hierarchy.

(Because of that, I suspect your `navigationController` is `nil` in `postInfo` too but I'd want to log that value to be sure.)

Comment: Ok cool thanks, I'll take a look into that and see if I can fix the problem and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Alternatively then, could I create an `NSNotificationCenter` variable to send the information to the `leaderboardViewController`?

Comment: If the original `leaderboardViewController` instance listens for a notification and calls its own `postInfo` in response, that could work.

Comment: Yeh that seems to have done the trick. I've removed the leaderboardViewController instance and when the block completes I've posted a notification to the leaderboardViewController that points to the `postInfo` method and it's worked which is cool. Thanks for your help in pointing out my mistake. I'll post my changes above